# MySql Query past in 90 days laravel version

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How to query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM invoice_client
WHERE date_sending < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -90 DAY) AND
      date_sending <> '0000-00-00' AND
      approve <> '1'
```

in laravel version ?

Comment: What did you try? What is the problem?

Comment: i dont know how to running this query in laravel eloquent.. did you know, sir?

Comment: Basically stackoverflow is not the place to ask someone to do the homework for you, it's a place to consult with other developers about problems that you have during the development.

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581763/laravel-5-search-records-30min-and-older-for-today/42583734#42583734

Comment: thats my problem, is not for homework. i try to learn laravel framework. but im not developer... but what's the problem for my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB::table('invoice_client')
   ->where("date_sending","!=","0000-00-00")
   ->where("date_sending",">",date("Y-m-d",time()-3600*24*90))
   ->where("approve","!=",1)
   ->get();
```

Can you try the above code?